# C# checkbox to string question

Tags: c#

I have 7 checkboxes.  What I want is to make one string for each of those checkboxs.  Meaning if I had....

Orange
apple
pear
plum
grape
tiger
red

And orange pear and red where checked.

I'd get a string that produced "orange ; pear ; red"

Comment: What framework? ASP.NET Forms, MVC, WinForms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is the problem, do you need just this?

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach(var cb in checkBoxes)
{
    if(cb.IsChecked)
    { 
        sb.Append(cb.Text);
        sb.Append(';');
    }
}
```

Comment: Good, but you might want to add a line of code in there to trim off the trailing semi-colon.

Comment: ArsenMkrt, you beat me for a few seconds. in addition, I we need to produce a string that is not like the name, we can use the Tag attribute of the checkbox to store the string.

Comment: Than you can use Tag, but I think the Text is exactly what he want, in wonforms, and Content.ToString() in wpf, just because I don't know is it wpf project or winform, I used name, I will change it now

Comment: and what is the reason of down voting?

Comment: Might be because your method will return `"orange;pear;red;"` when OP requested for `"orange ; pear ; red"`

Comment: still no reason to down vote i, simple change sb.Append(';'); to sb.Append(' ;');

Answer (score 3):

What I usually do when wanting to concat strings with a given separator, is putting my strings in a string array, then use the `String.Join` method.  Example :

```
string.Join(";", new string[] { "test1", "test2", "test3" }); // Which outputs test1;test2;test3
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use something similar to:

```
List<CheckBox> boxes;
String result = String.Join(" ; ", boxes.Where(box => box.Checked)
                                        .Select(box => box.Text).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var values = (from c in new[] { c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7 }
              where c.Checked
              select c.Text).ToArray();
var result = string.Join(";", values);
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify WinForms versus WPF; I will assume WinForms but code is nearly identical for WPF (replace `Checked` by `IsChecked` and `Text` by `Tag`). The `CheckBox` control has a `Checked` property indicating whether or not the `CheckBox` is in the checked state. So say that you `CheckBox`es are in an array `CheckBox[] checkBoxes`. Then you could say

```
List<string> checkedItems = new List<string>();
for(int i = 0; i < checkBoxes.Length; i++) {
    CheckBox checkBox = checkBoxes[i];
    if(checkBox.Checked) {
        checkedItems.Add(checkBox.Text);
    }
}
string result = String.Join(" ; ", checkedItems.ToArray());
```

Of course, that imperative and yucky. Let's get happy with some nice declarative code in LINQ:

```
string result = String.Join(
                     " ; ", 
                     checkBoxes.Where(cb => cb.Checked)
                               .Select(cb => cb.Text)
                               .ToArray()
                );
```

If your `CheckBox`es are not in array, you could start by putting them in array via

```
CheckBox[] checkBoxes = new[] { c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7 };
```

where `c1`, `c2`, ..., `c7` are your `CheckBox`es.